# magento .htaccess configuration issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, magento-1.8

Hey guys I have magento installed in two places and I am facing htaccess issues in both the places.

First issue in my  **LOCALHOST.**

**Install path:**
wamp\www\magento\fresh_1.8.1.0

I have installed magento and its working fine. This issue occurs when I use SEO Rewrite to remove index and for proper url. When I am tring to access my category or any other menu item I get page Not Found.

[This is my htaccess file information](http://pastebin.com/kAEETQTn)

I have tried other help from here but it dint help me out. I have tried to rewite my base too but it dint work

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /magento/fresh_1.8.1.0/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /magento/fresh_1.8.1.0/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I face same issue in **webserver** too

**server path:**
www.mysite.com\public_html

Any help would be great tnx.

Comment: Do your apache using rewrites?

Comment: tnx Martin it was not enable.